# Rails generating a new directory multiple levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dir

i have built this little app that generates a excel document. i am trying to make a directory to stick it in. these documents are built differently depending on the `@agency` that people select. so i made this method to return the path since the path is used in a few places.

```
def reportsheet_dir
  file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/reportsheets/#{@agency.downcase.gsub("_","")}"
end
```

At the beginning of the method that creates the document i have this method that supposedly builds directories but it doest seem to be working

```
Dir.mkdir(reportsheet_dir) unless File.exists?(reportsheet_dir)
```

I keep getting. this
and i get

```
Errno::ENOENT at /addons/agency_report_builders 
No such file or directory -/Users/fortknokx/Work/toolkit/public/reportsheets/empowerlogicbuilder
```

I think its because its multiple levels deep?? since public/`reportsheets/agency_name/file_name` has to be made. i could just go and make the folders but i would like to just make the dir each time because new agencies could be made at any time. is this possible?

Comment: thanks i didn't know how to phrase it and i wasn't getting any good search results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `FileUtils.mkdir_p()`

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p

It will recursively create non-existent directories.  `Dir.mkdir` will not.